# Separating what is migrated and restored with USMT

Tags: backup, sccm, usmt

I am currently running System Center Config Manager at my workplace. We have integrated MDT and are running a UDI on all of our PXE deployments.

I have a ton of MDT Task Sequences that use the UDI and I have started looking into USMT.

Currently we are backing up the data manually before we wish to do a re-install and moving this data back across after the installation is finished, though we wish to streamline this operation.

We currently back up our data to a local share (\BACKUPNAS\USMT) and once done move the contents of the folder we create back to the desktop and separate our the other files like Docs back to Docs and so forth.

I wish to have a similar setup with USMT. I need to backup the entire drive and then move the entire backup onto %SYSTEMDRIVE% once completed, during this time USMT can happily move docs to docs, videos to videos and so on.

To do this should I split the USMT files into two? One for backing up and one for restoring?